# Can you pass parameters into a scheduled Azure Webjob

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-triggered

I have a console app which runs daily on an azure webjob.
I am trying pass in parameters into the scheduled web job without redeploying.

I have seen that you could add params onto the webhook Url however since Azure Scheduler depercated you can't seem to edit the Webhooks to add on the `?arguments={your arguments}`.
I have also tried using environment variables but the console app can not access them.

If any of this helps.
I publish the console app through visual studio.
The webjob type is triggered.
I use a settings.job file to set the cron

```
{
  "schedule": "0 0 5 * * *",
}
```

Comment: What kind of parameter it will be? The parameter value will be different on each execution?

Comment: im looking to pass a couple strings. It won't be different every execution, just want to be able to change those string values without re-publishing code.